# OpenVPN - TLS Error: TLS handshake failed. Does this mean someone is trying to bruteforce in?

Tags: security, openvpn

Ive been using OpenVPN setup on my router for accessing various things on the network while I am remote. Once in a while I check the logs to make sure everything looks in order. To my surprise when I went to go check today I saw the following message popup every few minutes (and the log goes back a few days, and its just non stop). With IP changing once in a while. The below IP is some Canadian IP and is not one of mine.

If I try to connect to my VPN while remote there is no issues, logs look correct (accepts cipher and everything) and VPN works as I would expect.

Ive looked around and can seem to only find people posting this when they are having issues setting up their VPN. But mine is set up and operational. So is someone trying to break in?

What are my options other than disabling VPN? To get as far as they are now do they need anything other than my IP? In other words, has any of my VPN information been compromised?

Please let me know if you need more logs, and thank you.

```
Aug 31 19:37:03 r6300 daemon.err openvpn[20867]: 149.56.14.253 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Aug 31 19:37:03 r6300 daemon.err openvpn[20867]: 149.56.14.253 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Aug 31 19:37:03 r6300 daemon.notice openvpn[20867]: 149.56.14.253 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Aug 31 19:37:04 r6300 daemon.notice openvpn[20867]: 149.56.14.253 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET6]::ffff:149.56.14.253:10011, sid=6a22eb44 5adb63fe
```

Comment: Just looks like regular port-scanning activity to me.

Comment: In that case nothing to really worry about? Just have to deal with log spam? And why would OpenVPN be the one sending errors? Shouldnt this be a firewall message if its port scanning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a few days of experimenting I think I found a solution. Hopefully this will be useful to someone in the future.

It appears that similar to trying to break in via SSH there are bots out there that try to get into your VPN? Makes sense. But just like SSH they scan the default ports looking for victims.

So solution here was to not use the default Open VPN port (1194). Its been about 24 hours since I made a change and so far so good.